# I can’t get rid of the black lines on a Bezier Curve

Tags: modeling

I’m new to Blender and exploring bezier curve objects.

These thin black lines appear around the curves, what are these?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. For clearer screenshots please use something like this: take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Please don't take photos of your monitor, these are hard to read and unhelpful diagnosing issues